# Подсчет одинаковых значений в массиве PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массивы:

```
$data = [
    array(
        [0] => "Автобусные",
        [1] => "Пешеходные"
    ),
    array(
        [0] => "Исторические",
        [1] => "Пешеходные",
        [2] => "Водные"
    ),
    array(
        [0] => "Пешеходные",
        [1] => "Тематические",
        [2] => "Исторические"
    )
];
```

Длинный способ:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $val) {
        if(!empty($val)) array_push($result, $val);
    }
}
$result = array_count_values($result);
```

Результат:

```
Array(
    [Автобусные] => 1
    [Пешеходные] => 3
    [Исторические] => 2
    [Водные] => 1
    [Тематические] => 1
)
```

Есть ли способ пересчитать значения в массивах быстрее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально имеем следующий массив:

```
$data = [
    ['Автобусные', 'Пешеходные' ],
    ['Исторические', 'Пешеходные', 'Водные'],
    ['Пешеходные', 'Тематические', 'Исторические']
];
```

Способ с `RecursiveIteratorIterator`:

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data)) as $v)
    $result[] = $v;

print_r(array_count_values($result));
```

Или вариант с использованием `call_user_func_array`:

```
print_r(array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data)));
```

Или вариант с использованием `array_reduce`:

```
print_r(array_count_values(array_reduce($data, 'array_merge', [])));
```